# set sub page for post type archive - wordpress

Tags: wordpress

1. I have **songs** post type
2. I have **songs** page : (i made page in wordpress panel) http://nabzetaraneh.ir/songs/
3. I have a page called **the_tops** : http://nabzetaraneh.ir/songs/the_tops/

**the_tops** parent is **songs**

but you can see 404

> permalinks on /%postname%/

Answer (score 0):

you should make a songs page template, and name it **archive-songs.php** (or whatever is the slug for your page), creating it in your pages control panel is not enough. Your custom post type has to have the archive option set to true. You should make a **single-songs.php** page template too, for individual songs.

Info [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Type_Templates)